# Proof of the Soundness Theorem

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Here's what I want to show.

If $\Delta$ is a set of formulas and $\alpha$ is a formula such that $\Delta \vdash \alpha$, then $\Delta \models \alpha$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $v$ be any truth assignment that satisfies $\Delta$. Since $\Delta \vdash \alpha$, there is a deduction $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ such that $\phi_n$ is $\alpha$.

The formulas $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{n-1}$ that appear in the deduction fall into exactly one of the three following categories:

1. They are instances of the axiom schema (hence, they are tautologies)
2. They are formulas in $\Delta$
3. They were inferred from previous formulas in the deduction by way of Modus Ponens.

Since it is the case that $\{\psi,\psi \to \phi\} \models \phi$, any formula in the deduction that was inferred via Modus Ponens is going to be satisfied by the truth assignment $v$.

If $\alpha$ is a formula in $\Delta$, then it is immediately satisfied by $v$ and $\Delta \models \alpha$.

If $\alpha$ is an instance of an axiom schema, then it is a tautology so it is immediately satisfied by $v$. So, $\Delta \models \alpha$

If $\alpha$ was inferred from previous formulas in the deduction via Modus Ponens, then it is going to be satisfied by the truth assignment $v$. So, $\Delta \models \alpha$.

We conclude, then, that $\Delta \models \alpha$, as was desired. $\Box$

Does the argument above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is Modus Ponens the only deduction rule? If not, you should verify the soundness of each one.

Comment: Modus Ponens is the only rule of inference, along with the three axiom schema. I've already proven that every instance of the three axiom schema yields a tautology

Comment: Great. Then that's all, I guess.

Comment: Alright nice, so the proof I wrote up works? if it's not too much trouble, then can you have a look at my proof of the Deduction Theorem too?